# Best way to get model1 objects only if related via 1:n, most recent model2 object fulfills filter requirement

Tags: django, django-models

We got Bundle related 1:n to Tracking. Tracking has "created" timestamp and "status" fields.

It has to be possible to get Bundle by status what means that only Bundles which have Tracking with the status related to it AND that Tracking with the status is the latest (most recent) one Tracking of the bundle (sorted by "created" field)

We have some implementations but what is the best way to do that via django orm, on database level, minimizing number of sql queries.

EDIT: code for models:

```
class Tracking(DateStampableBase):

    NEW = 0
    PROCESSING_AT_FC = 1
    PACKED = 2
    SHIPPED_TO_PARTICIPANTS = 3
    DELIVERED_TO_PARTICIPANTS = 4
    SHIPPED_TO_LAB = 5
    DELIVERED_TO_LAB = 6

    BUNDLE_STATUSES = (
        (NEW, 'new'),
        (PROCESSING_AT_FC, 'processing_at_fc'),
        (PACKED, 'packed'),
        (SHIPPED_TO_PARTICIPANTS, 'shipped_to_participants'),
        (DELIVERED_TO_PARTICIPANTS, 'delivered_to_participants'),
        (SHIPPED_TO_LAB, 'shipped_to_lab'),
        (DELIVERED_TO_LAB, 'delivered_to_lab'),
    )

    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=BUNDLE_STATUSES, default=NEW)
    bundle = models.ForeignKey(Bundle)


class Bundle(DateStampableBase):
    pass


class DateStampableBase(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Please add the code for `Bundle` and `Tracking` model.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the models structure, I guess your best option is to use `select_related`. This way you only hit the DB once to get a fully populated Queryset, and you work over that queryset with filters, sort and so on.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Edit: if I'm understanding correctly, you want this:

```
Bundle.objects.filter(tracking__status=1).order_by("tracking__created")
```

where the `1` is the status input you are filtering for.

Comment: What else do you need to know regarding these two models?

Comment: How they're related, at least, and the fields you name in your question. Something like the first code of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239601

Comment: they are related Bundle 1:n Tracking and I named fields involved in the problem. Input: status. Output: Bundle which has Tracking with the status from input, if that Tracking is latest one. Can't state it more clearly.